# Spying on event callbacks with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, closures, jasmine

I am using Jasmine to test a Backbone.js view within a Require.js module.

Why does my test fail if I don't wrap the callback in an anonymous function?

Here's the test:

```
describe("view extension", function () {
    // extendedView is an instance of ExtendedView()
    spyOn(extendedView, 'onOpen');

    // open the element, which should trigger an event
    extendedView.open();

    expect(extendedView.onOpen).toBeDefined();
    expect(extendedView.onOpen).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Failing:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    open: function () {
        this.trigger('open');
    }
});

var ExtendedView = BaseView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.on('open', self.onOpen);
    },
    onOpen: function() {
        console.log('I heard myself open');
    }
});
```

Passing with the following revision in `.initialize()`:

```
    self.on('open', function () { self.onOpen() });
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working is that you are installing the spy on an *instance* and doing this *after* the event handler is bound. The sequence of event is roughly like this:

1. The instance that is going to be assigned to `extendedView` is created so `ExtendedView`'s`initialize` method executes `self.on('open', self.onOpen);`.  **At that time** `self.onOpen` evaluates to the **original** function defined by the `ExtendedView` class.
2. Then you set a spy on `extendedView.onOpen`. This changes the value of `onOpen` for `extendedView` (and **only** for `extendedView`) to that of a new spy.
3. `extendedView.open()` is called. Because `self.on` was called originally with the value of `self.onOpen` set for the `ExtendedView` class, it is this **original** function which is called , *not* the spy that now resides in `extendedView.onOpen`.

The reason it work when you use the anonymous function is that the anonymous function gets the value of `self.onOpen` whenever an `open` event happens, which in your test means this value is obtained **after** you've set the spy.

You'd have to spy on the class methods rather than on the instance. Something like:

```
    spyOn(ExtendedView.prototype, 'onOpen');

    [...]    

    expect(ExtendedView.prototype.onOpen).toBeDefined();
    expect(ExtendedView.prototype.onOpen).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Attempting to access the class with `.prototype` throws an error in the test:`spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for onOpen()`. This could be because the modules are pulled into the test with `require`.